# Class inherited from class without default constructor

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, default-constructor

Right now I have a class `A` that inherits from class `B`, and `B` does not have a default constructor. I am trying the create a constructor for `A` that has the exact same parameters for `B`'s constructor

```
struct B {
  int n;
  B(int i) : n(i) {}
};

struct A : B {
  A(int i) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

but I get:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘B::B()’
note: candidates are: B::B(int)
```

How would I fix this error?

Comment: Please post your current code

Comment: @Ramon Zarazua--why? I've already gotten the answer...

Comment: @wrongusername Because Stackoverflow is a collective and aims to help more people than just the asker. People with the same problem will search for this question and use the answers for a solution to their problem. But in order to do that they need to know that their problem is the same as yours. By providing code that exhibits your problem, other people can much easier and quicker determine whether the question (and ultimately the answers) apply to them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The constructor should look like this:

```
A(int i) : B(i) {}
```

The bit after the colon means, "initialize the B base class sub object of this object using its `int` constructor, with the value i".

I guess that you didn't provide an initializer for B, and hence by default the compiler attempts to initialize it with the non-existent no-args constructor.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what that means, Steve! I didn't realize there was an initializer

Answer (score 9):

You need to invoke the base constructor via your class' initializer list.

Example:

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    C(int x) : B(x)
    {
    }

};
```

When you don't initialize B explicitly it will try to use the default constructor which has no parameters.