# Initialize base class with no default constructor in constructor of derived class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I'm trying to create a subclass `secondary` which could be used with a parameter as well as it's overriding class `primary`. Now I get

> no matching function to call

error. Could someone help me?

My code:
primary.h:

```
#ifndef PRIMARY_H
#define PRIMARY_H


class primary
{
    public:
        primary(int x);
        virtual ~primary();
    protected:
    private:
        int primary_x;
};

#endif // PRIMARY_H
```

primary.cpp:

```
#include "primary.h"

primary::primary(int x)
{
    primary_x = x;
}

primary::~primary()
{
    //dtor
}
```

secondary.h:

```
#ifndef SECONDARY_H
#define SECONDARY_H
#include "primary.h"


class secondary : public primary
{
    public:
        secondary();
        virtual ~secondary();
    protected:
    private:
};

#endif // SECONDARY_H
```

secondary.cpp:

```
#include "secondary.h"

secondary::secondary()
{
    //ctor
}

secondary::~secondary()
{
    //dtor
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class inherited from class without default constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714162/class-inherited-from-class-without-default-constructor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you don't have a default constructor the compiler complains that it can't create an object for `primary`, you should either add a parameter to the `secondary` constructor / give it a default value:

```
class secondary : public primary
{
    public:
        secondary(int x);
        virtual ~secondary();
    protected:
    private:
};
```

And then call the base class constructor:

```
secondary::secondary(int x) : primary(x)
{
    //ctor
}
```

Or:

```
secondary::secondary() : primary(5)
{
    //ctor
}
```

Or just add a default constructor for `primary`:

```
class primary
{
    public:
        primary(int x);
        primary() : primary_x(0) {}
        virtual ~primary();
    protected:
    private:
        int primary_x;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This whole problem looks like you wanted to do something, but you forgot what it was, in the middle of writing the code.

The constructor of `primary` expects an `int` and it's not getting it, because

```
secondary::secondary() { }
```

is equivalent to:

```
secondary::secondary() : primary() { }
```

Compiler tries to default-construct `primary`, but it's not default-constructible. Because you declared a constructor taking `int`, the default constructor is no longer generated by the compiler.

Solutions:

- modify the derived class' constructor:

  ```
  secondary::secondary() : primary(10) { } // dummy value
  ```

  or mimic the base class constructor's signature:

  ```
  secondary::secondary(int x) : primary(x) { }
  ```
- modify the base class - make `primary` default-constructible, i.e. declare constructor as:

  ```
  primary(int x = 10) // dummy default argument
  ```

  or add a default-constructor overload:

  ```
  primary() = default;
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
public:
    secondary();
```

should also take an integer:

```
public:
    secondary(int x);
```

and then ctor definition:

```
secondary::secondary(int x) : primary(x)
{
    //ctor
}
```

Comment: This does not compile.

Comment: what is the error? AH, ok, i see ;) `secondary::secondary()` should take int like in declaration.

Comment: You took `x` out of nowhere.